# using bitmap to find resources of an imageview in another layout

Tags: android

Is it possible to use bitmap to get resources from an image view that is in another layout?

I am able to get resource from the image using this code below

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.large_icon);
```

But is there a way to getResouce from an imageview? I want to be able to choose an image from gallery or take a photo and put It in imageView. And to process the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick image from galery or take a photo from camera - you should ask system to do it and the use bitmap object to process it and to set it to image view

First, ask system to provide image to you:

```
    public void onSelectFromGalery() {
            Intent requestIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            requestIntent.setType("image/jpeg,image/png");
            startActivityForResult(requestIntent, SELECT_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Then process result:

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (requestCode == SELECT_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16 && data.getClipData() != null) {
                ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                    Uri uri = item.getUri();
                    String path = getImagePathFromUri(uri);
                    if (path != null) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                        //process bitmap
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }
            } else if (data.getData() != null) {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                String path = getImagePathFromUri(imageUri);
                if (path != null) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                        //process bitmap
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea how to initialize imageView that is in another layout?